# How to hide message window in MS SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please look at the attached picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> +<kbd>R</kbd>

toggles (hides or shows) the Messages window.

You also can display results in a separate window as follows:

Navigate to Tools | Options | Query Results | SQL Server | [Results to Grid] or [Results to Text] 
Check [Display results in a separate tab]

Comment: Anyone know if Microsoft plans to add a simple "X - Close" button to this tab? Seems like it's not conforming to their corporate UI standards. Tabs should always be closable.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes CTRL + R might not work. In such scenarios you can try:
Tools -> Options -> Keyboard and then click **Reset**

Should work now.